# Raw images to PNG in Python

Tags: python

So I'm pretty new to Python, and I'm trying to write a script that will convert from raw to png. This is what I have so far:

```
rawData = open('filename', 'r').read()
imgSize = (515, 515)
img = Image.fromstring(1, imgSize, rawData)
im.save('Test.png')
```

I keep getting an error message that says "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

There's gotta be something terribly wrong with my code that I don't see. Anybody?

Comment: Why do you think the exception is lying?

Comment: Well, it is telling you exactly what is wrong; why do you think the message is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a variable named `filename`, so you should do

```
rawData = open(filename, 'r').read()
```

Note that it does not have quotes. Otherwise you are saying the string literal `"filename"` is your path, which I strongly doubt.

Comment: The name of the raw file is 0, so should I just do open(0, 'r').read()?

Cuz I tried that before and it still doesn't work

Comment: Either provide a full path e.g. `"C:\FolderA\FolderB\File.png"` or a relative path `"FolderB\File.png"` if you can traverse from your working directory. If the file is in the same folder that you are working, you can just refer to the file name `"0.png"` or whatever.

Comment: Also, you use `im.save()`.  Don't your mean `img`?